# How to output JSON from recordset in Dreamweaver with minimal manual code?

Tags: sql, json, dreamweaver

I got a pretty difficult task. Myself I'm experienced with many "web" languages like JavaScript, PHP, Node.js, a bit of Python/Django etc.

Now, the problem is that I'm going to teach some students how to integrate Adobe Edge Animate with a database. So I'm going to use JSON as the means of communicating with the server.

Problem is, they don't know anything about SQL, HTML or PHP, and they've used Dreamweaver to make websites up until now.

So the big question is, how can one output the result of a so called recordset as JSON with as little manual coding as possible?